# Spring Data REST - Null fields after POST - When/Where should I initialize them?

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-rest

My NoteRepository extends CrudRepository<Note, Long>. A Note has a title, noteBody, and dateCreated. A POST request to /notes would include the title and the noteBody, and I want the dateCreated to automatically be LocalDateTime.now().

Is it acceptable to

```
@Entity
public class Note {
    ...
    @Column(name="DTCREATED")
    private LocalDateTime dateCreated = LocalDateTime.now();
```

or am I supposed to do it a different way?

Answer (score 1):

In My code, I achieved this by using @PrePersist and @PreUpdate annotations, this annotation will be called when the entity gets persisted/updated

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to initialize `LocalDateTime` instance manually, You can do this with new annotations;

```
@CreationTimestamp
@Column(name = "create_datetime", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private LocalDateTime createDateTme;

@UpdateTimestamp
@Column(name = "lastupdate_datetime", nullable = false)
private LocalDateTime lastUpdateDateTime;
```

These annotations are available in `org.hibernate.annotations` package. When you save instance of your entity, just don't initialize them.

Comment: Is there a database performance difference between `@CreationTimestamp` / `@UpdateTimestamp` vs `@PrePersist` / `@PreUpdate`? Or is one preferred over the other?

Comment: No database performance different. Both are happen in the JVM. This `@CreationTimestamp` and `@UpdateTimestamp` annotations specifically designed to work with `create_datetime` and `update_datetime` columns. They also only support types like `java.time.LocalDate`, `java.time.LocalDateTime`, `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, `java.sql.Date`, `java.sql.Time` and `java.sql.Timestamp`. Hibernate initializes them on the event of `save` or `update`. `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` annotations are JPA entity event listeners. You can use them with any type as long as you initialize them.